Как изменить значение ячейки в таблице dearpygui?
подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в dearpygui функция, изменяющая значение ячейки в таблице? Значения таблицы зачитываются из базы данных.
Вот код:
with dpg.table(header_row=True, no_host_extendX=True, delay_search=True,
                            borders_innerH=True, borders_outerH=True, borders_innerV=True,
                            borders_outerV=True, context_menu_in_body=True, row_background=True,
                            policy=dpg.mvTable_SizingFixedFit, height=300,
                            scrollY=True):
        dpg.add_table_column(label="ID", tag="idcol")
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Имя книги", tag="namecol")
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Автор", tag="authorcol")
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Статус", tag="statuscol")
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Тип", tag="typecol")
        
        for i in range(len(reformated)):
            book = reformated[i]
            with dpg.table_row():
                dpg.add_text(book.id, tag = "idrow")
                dpg.add_text(book.name, tag = "namerow")
                dpg.add_text(name_shorter(book.author), tag = "authorrow")
                dpg.add_text(Status(book.status).name,  tag = "statusrow")
                dpg.add_text(Type(book.type).name, tag = "typerow")

    close_database(base)



Всё оказалось достаточно просто: Я сделал уникальные теги под каждую ячейку:

for i in range(len(reformated)):
            book = reformated[i]
            with dpg.table_row():
                dpg.add_text(book.id, tag = f"idrow_{i}")
                dpg.add_text(book.name, tag = f"namerow_{i}")
                dpg.add_text(name_shorter(book.author), tag = f"authorrow_{i}")
                dpg.add_text(Status(book.status).name,  tag = f"statusrow_{i}")
                dpg.add_text(Type(book.type).name, tag = f"typerow_{i}")


и изменил значения под конкретную ячейку
dpg.set_value("statusrow_2", value)

Вот и всё!
